# upgrade version smarty template engine

Tags: php, smarty

my old version of `smarty` is 2.6.20 now i need to upgrade old version to new version 3.1.1. but in new version of `smarty`(3.1.1) i see change libs file directory. can i switch to new version without change my php code ? how to ?

old smarty directory: libs/

```
/internals/
/plugins/
Config_File.class.php
debug.tpl
Smarty.class.php
Smarty_Compiler.class.php
```

new smarty directory : libs/

```
/plugins/
/sysplugins/
Smarty.class.php
SmartyBC.class.php
debug.tpl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather unlikely that an upgrade can be made without touching your code/templates. For a list of things to look out for, read the following upgrade notes:

- [Smarty 2 Notes](http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/source/browse/trunk/distribution/SMARTY_2_BC_NOTES.txt)
- [Smarty 3.0 Notes](http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/source/browse/trunk/distribution/SMARTY_3.0_BC_NOTES.txt)
- [Smarty 3.1 Notes](http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/source/browse/trunk/distribution/SMARTY_3.1_NOTES.txt)

Comment: The links have changed to:

* [Smarty 2 BC Notes](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/master/SMARTY_2_BC_NOTES.txt)
* [Smarty 3 BC Notes](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/master/SMARTY_3.0_BC_NOTES.txt)
* [Smarty 3.1 Notes](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/master/SMARTY_3.1_NOTES.txt)

Comment: Links are down, but you can find all the documentation in version branches https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/tree/support/3.1 https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/tree/support/2.6 https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty